# Weird error with memoir and listings

Tags: listings, memoir

The following MWE crashes:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\newlistof{lstlisting}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    struct x;
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@nameuse {mem@lstlisting}{01}}\reserved@a 
l.11   \end{lstlisting}
                       
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

For some strange reason, the `amsmath` package is required. The trouble seems to lie in the `\newlistof` line, commenting that one goes through with no problems.

Comment: You can remove both `amsmath` and the `\newlistof` (there's `\lstlistoflistings` already). Why do you need it?

Comment: @Werner, no idea. Inherited stuff from way back. Cleaned up now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
\newlistof{foo}{ext}{name}
```

a new macro is defined: `\foo` (as in `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures`)

In this case

```
 \newlistof{lstlisting}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
```

defines `\lstlisting` which is also the same as `\begin{lstlisting}` so you just broke the `lstlisting` environment.

Though the fault is `memoir`'s, `memoir` should check the existence of `\foo` before defining it.

This bug has been noted and will be fixed in a future version of `memoir`

Comment: Boy, do I feel dumb...